# Eclipse Folding Custom Editor

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I have implemented my custom editor, and now need folding for

- comments (`//I am a comment`)
- `function (){}`

So how can I do this...

Comment: This is too broad for a Stack Overflow question. Assuming your editor is based on TextEditor see [Folding in Eclipse Text Editors](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Folding-in-Eclipse-Text-Editors/folding.html)

Comment: yes I take a look at this, but is there no an available class from eclipse which supports folding for commenting or should I do it on my own?

Comment: It is up to you to write the code than decides where the folding occurs.

Comment: I only Need it for comments like this /* */